# Search based on a field value of subcollection in angularfirestore collection

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

Trying to search in a list based on the name field of firebase database using angularfirestore. It does not even show any error in console. the result returning from the code in service is an empty array. I filtered and map the payload data in constructor to get the async and access the nested objects in the database

[image: firebase collection]

list.html:

```html
    <input type="search" 
          class="form-control"
          [(ngModel)]="searchValue"
          [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
          (keyup)="searchMasjid()"
          placeholder="Name...">
  <div *ngIf="masjids$ | async; let masjids; else loading">
    <div class="card mb-1" *ngFor="let masjid of masjids">
      <div class="card-body d-flex justify-content-between">
        <div>
          <h5 class="mb-1">{{masjid.masjidInfo.jagah}}-{{masjid.masjidInfo.name}}</h5>
          <small>{{masjid.masjidInfo.address}}</small>
        </div>
```

list.ts:

```js
export class MasjidListComponent{
  public masjids$: Observable<IMasjid[]>;
  masjids : Array<any>;
  searchValue: string = "";
  filterMasjidName: Array<any>;

  constructor(public firebaseService: FirebaseService, 
              public af: AngularFirestore){
                this.masjids$ = this.af.collection('masjids').snapshotChanges().pipe(
                  map( actions => actions.map(masjid => {
                    let data = masjid.payload.doc.data() as IMasjid;
                    let id = masjid.payload.doc.id;
                    return { id, ...data };
                  }))
                )
              }

  searchMasjid(){
    let value = this.searchValue;
    this.firebaseService.searchMasjids(value).subscribe(
     result => {
        this.filterMasjidName = result;
        this.masjids = this.combineMasjids(result, this.filterMasjidName)
     } 
    )
  }

  combineMasjids(a, b){
    let result = [];
    a.filter(x => {
      return b.filter(x2 =>{
        if(x2.payload.doc.id == x.payload.doc.id){
          result.push(x2);
        }
      });
    });
    return result;
  }
}
```

service.ts:

```js
searchMasjids(searchValue){
    return this.db.collection('masjids.masjidInfo', 
    ref=>ref.where('name', '>=', searchValue)
    .where('name', '<=', searchValue + '\uf8ff')).snapshotChanges()
  }
}
```

Comment: If you get no errors, but get no results, that typically means the code executed correctly, but didn't return any results. What did you search for?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, your `searchMasjids` method is already consuming the results, since it calls `snapshotChanges()`. This means that the caller of `searchMasjids` gets back a `QuerySnapshot`, while it's actually expecting a `Query`.

You should instead return the collection/query:

```
searchMasjids(searchValue){
    return this.db.collection(
      'masjids.masjidInfo', 
      ref => ref.where('name', '>=', searchValue)
                .where('name', '<=', searchValue + '\uf8ff')
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: when I remove the snapshotChanges(), .subscribe() in component is throwing error. appreciate the help...thanks...